# Change Pages to Post in Woocommerce without Plugin

Tags: posts

Whenever I have made a website with Wordpress, the Woocommerce orders are saved as a post. I have several websites where the Woocommerce order page has this url:

> https://domain.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order

And each order has a url like this:

> https://domain.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=31056&action=edit

But on the last website I made, the Woocommerce orders, instead of being posts, are pages and their url is this:

> https://domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-orders

And each order has a url like this:

> https://domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-orders&action=edit&id=3463

I have not configured this website differently, I do not have plugins that change that configuration.

There is a plugin that requires Woocommerce orders to be posts and not pages. How can I change that configuration without using plugins?

I know it must be some configuration but it has never happened to me before.

Thank you

Comment: You'll have to ask the plugin's support team about this. Third-party plugin support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: WooCommerce changed how orders are stored: https://woo.com/document/high-performance-order-storage/ If a plugin isn’t working you’ll need to run it in a compatibility mode. That article has mor information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, in the end it is super easy, I was checking the configurations of my other websites a lot and everything was in one configuration.

In

> Woocommerce > Settings > Advanced > Features >

It is defined how the orders will be saved and if they already exist they can be easily migrated.

Apparently (according to the config) it is high performance to save them as pages instead of posts.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

To change the WooCommerce order pages back to posts without using a plugin, you can modify the post type of WooCommerce orders in WordPress. This can be achieved by adding custom code to your theme's functions.php file or creating a custom plugin. Here are the steps to do this:

1. Access Your WordPress Files: You can access your WordPress files through an FTP client or a file manager provided by your hosting provider.
2. Locate the Theme's `functions.php` File: If you want to add the code to your theme, navigate to your WordPress theme's directory, usually located at `wp-content/themes/your-theme-name/`.
3. Edit `functions.php`: Open the `functions.php` file for editing. You can use a code editor or a plain text editor.
4. Add the Following Code to `functions.php`:

```php
/**
 * Change WooCommerce order post type to 'post'.
 */
function change_woocommerce_order_post_type() {
    global $wpdb;

    // Define the new post type (in this case, 'post').
    $new_post_type = 'post';

    // Define the old post type (WooCommerce order post type, which is 'shop_order').
    $old_post_type = 'shop_order';

    // Update the post type in the database.
    $wpdb->query(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "UPDATE {$wpdb->posts} SET post_type = %s WHERE post_type = %s",
            $new_post_type,
            $old_post_type
        )
    );
}

// Hook the function to run during the 'init' action.
add_action('init', 'change_woocommerce_order_post_type');
```

5. Save the File: After adding the code, save the `functions.php` file.
6. Clear WordPress Cache: If you have a caching plugin installed, make sure to clear the cache.
7. Test: Now, when you go to your WooCommerce orders page, you should see that orders are displayed as posts rather than pages.

This code hooks into the WordPress `init` action and updates the post type for WooCommerce orders in the database from 'shop_order' to 'post'. It effectively changes the orders from being treated as pages to being treated as regular posts.

Make sure to backup your site before making any code changes, and be cautious when editing theme files or adding custom code.

Comment: Excellent snippet, I'll leave it saved